# Mockito mocking retrytemplate.execute and return mocked response

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

Below is the code I want to test:

```
@Autowired
RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

MyResponse response;

response = retryTemplate.execute(new RetryCallback<Mono<MyResponse>, RuntimeException>() {
    public Mono<MyResponse> doRetry(RetryContext context) {
        return webclient.post.body(Mono.just(requestBodyObj), RequestBodyObj.class).retrieve().bodyToMono(MyResponse.class);
    }
});
```

Below is the test case I am trying, but getting Invalid use of matchers exception. Also, I am not sure if my below code would work. Pls guide:

```
MyResponse myResponseObj = new MyResponse();

when(retryTemplate.execute(any(RetryCallback.class))).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
        RetryCallback retry = invocation.getArgument(0);
        when(retry.doWithRetry(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(Mockito.eq(Mono.just(myResponseObj)))
        return retry.doWithRetry(null);
    });
```

Pls guide what is the mistake here and how can I return `myResponseObj` whenever `retry.doWithRetry` is called.

Comment: in your case you'll need to `when(retryTemplate.execute(any(RetryCallback.class), isNull(), isNull())).thenReturn(myResponseObj);`

Answer (score 0):

Please have a view for below retryTemplate execute method:

```
public final <T, E extends Throwable> T execute(RetryCallback<T, E> retryCallback) throws E {
        return this.doExecute(retryCallback, (RecoveryCallback)null, (RetryState)null);
}
```

When we call retryTemplate.execute(retryCallback), the other two arguments in doExecute method are null, so basically this is the reason why you get Invalid use of matchers exception.